Need help in sum of different products
I need a better formula for sum of different products in a same row in excel.
I am using this formula for sum of products (B3*C3)+(D3*E3)+(F3*G3)+(H3*I3)+(J3*H3)+... and so on. It takes too much time to write the above formula
I have tried SUMPRODUCT formula too but it didn't work.
IMPORTANT: some of the cell has no value or 0


It didn't work? Can you elaborate what you mean? You got an error, the value wasn't as expected? How did you setup the inputs? But yeah, the way your data is structured it'd make writing a sumproduct also pretty cumbersome. But maybe there's something else you can do to help, you mentions it's different products, so is this a case of price * quantity? and there's a name of the product somewhere? We can use that to write a better formula.

in Cell B3, D3, F3, H3, J3 is the quantity and C3, E3, G3, I3 is the price and i need total sale in A3

Hi, added another answer which should resolve this for you in a single formula.

To do this in a single calculation I staggered the ranges I was referencing for the logic to check the Qty and Price text, so the arrays it produces would line up the results otherwise the 1,0's would alternate and the multiplication would always result in a 0. To see what I mean you'll notice the quantity starts a B and ends at L, whereas the Price starts at C and ends at M.
=LET( Qty,  --(B2:L2="Qty")*B3:L3,
   Price, --(C2:M2="Price")*C3:M3,
   SUMPRODUCT(Qty,Price) 
)


